# Truncate a long text on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, truncate

I have a question!
My div can have a long text. This div doesn't have fixed height, and I have trouble on mobile phones.

For instance, my device has width 320px, but the inner div has width 454px.
It happens to long words.
You can see my issue on [`codepen`](http://codepen.io/llsandro/pen/YNemOm).

Can I fix it only with CSS?

I would be grateful if you could help me to fix this!

Comment: Do you mean that the inner box needs to have a fixed width that's larger than the device?

Comment: No, the inner box doesn't have a fixed width. The inner box needs to have a width 100%.

Comment: If you don't want your div to have a fixed height, how do you want to truncate its content? Should it have a max height? Should it have the height of the window?

Comment: Also, you mentioned height once and width another time, which one is the problem?

Comment: Simply just make the div with a width of 100% on mobile devices?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Comment: My problem with scrolling [link](https://youtu.be/Lrs2M6oX304)

Comment: CBroe, thank you very much!!!

Comment: My solution:

`
div.breaking {
  hyphens: auto;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

use this css code:

```css
p{width:100px;
height:auto;
border:2px solid #000;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;}
```

```html
<p> this is a biggggggggggggggggggg word</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't have a fixed width.
My solution:

<pre>
.content {
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
      word-break: break-all;
      word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
          hyphens: auto;
}
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my issue with this css code:

```
.breaking {
     -ms-word-break: break-all;
      word-break: break-all;
      word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
          hyphens: auto;
}
```

[CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe), thanks for your help.